# How to edit sessions parameters on Oracle 10g XE?

Tags: database, oracle

default is 49

how to edit to higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to issue the following command (connected as a user that has alter system privileges, sys will do it)

alter system set sessions=*numberofsessions* scope=spfile;

Have you been getting an ORA-12516 or ORA-12520 error?
If so it's probably a good idea to increase the number of processes too

alter system set processes=*numberofprocesses* scope=spfile;

IIRC you'll need to bounce the database after issuing these commands.
This link http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/php/pdf/underground-php-oracle-manual.pdf has some good information about configuring XE.
I consulted it when I ran into similar issues using XE.

Answer (score 0):

You can check connection limits in order to fine tune the session/process limits:

http://zhefeng.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/ora-12516-error-tnslistener-could-not-find-available-handler-with-matching-protocol-stack/?

Step1: take a look at the processes limition.

select * from gv$resource_limit;

Step2: increase the parameter from 150 (default) to 300 (or any other desired number)

sql>alter system set processes=300 scope=spfile;

Step3: reboot the database to let parameter taking effect.

ps: check link for more info.